# Using jQuery AJAX to pass checkbox data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to pass values of selected checkboxes to a PHP file using jQuery's `.getJSON` method.

**Problem:** The values does not seem to be received by the PHP file. I am using `print_f` to see if the PHP file has received the form data. Looking at the return data, the error PHP throws [`Undefined index:`] tell me that the 2 arrays `$bedroom` and `$bathroom` are not defined. How do I get this to work?

**HTML Code**

```
<form action="form_ajax.php" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="bedroom[]" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="bedroom[]" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="bedroom[]" value="3">

  <input type="checkbox" name="bathroom[]" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="bathroom[]" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="bathroom[]" value="3">

  <input type="submit" id="button" value="submit!!!">
</form>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(function() {

    $("#button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var other_data = "hello";
        $.getJSON("form.php", {some-other-data: other_data, bedroom: bedroom[], bathroom: bathroom[]}, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });

});
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php

$bedroom = $_GET['bedroom'];
$bathroom = $_GET['bathroom'];

print_r($bedroom);
print_r($bathroom);
```

?>

Comment: I think getJSON is used to GET data from the server, not sending it

Comment: I want to send some data, and get the result in JSON format. Can I still use `getJSON` in this case?

Comment: Yes :) the data is send in the second parameter of the getJSON function and should be visible in the PHP $_GET object. If you still have a problem, check your JSON syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the jQuery documentation of [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) the data is passed as querystring variables, so I would suggest you try to use `$_GET` instead:

```
$bedroom = $_GET['bedroom'];
$bathroom = $_GET['bathroom'];
```

**Edit, how to send all form-data to the php-file:**

If you add an id attribute to the form-tag, you can easily use jQuery to serialize the form, like this, and pass that as the data object in `$.getJSON()`:

```
$.getJSON("form.php", $("#your-form-id").serialize());
```

Then all your selected checkboxes should be passed along to the PHP-file.

Comment: great, thanks. Now I dont know how to send the values of the selected checkboxes to the PHP file

Comment: See my edited answer on how to serialize the form with jQuery, to pass all data with the call.